# Returning multiple columns from a single pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to parse a single single column of pyspark dataframe and get dataframe with multiple columns.My dataframe is as follows:

```
   a  b               dic
0  1  2  {'d': 1, 'e': 2}
1  3  4  {'d': 7, 'e': 0}
2  5  6  {'d': 5, 'e': 4}
```

I want to parse the dic column and get dataframe as follows. I am looking forward to use pandas UDF if possible. My intended output is as follows:

```
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  1  2
1  3  4  7  0
2  5  6  5  4
```

Here is my attempt to solution:

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("c", IntegerType()),
    StructField("d", IntegerType())])

@pandas_udf(schema,PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def do_someting(dic_col):
    return (pd.DataFrame(dic_col))

df.apply(add_json).show(10)
```

But this gives error 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'apply'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform first to JSON string by replacing simple quotes by double quotes, then use [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#from_json) to convert it into a struct or map column.

If you know the schema of the dict you can do it like this:

```
data = [
    (1,   2,  "{'c': 1, 'd': 2}"),
    (3,   4,  "{'c': 7, 'd': 0}"),
    (5,   6,  "{'c': 5, 'd': 4}")
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["a", "b", "dic"])

schema = StructType([
    StructField("c", StringType(), True),
    StructField("d", StringType(), True)
])

df = df.withColumn("dic", from_json(regexp_replace(col("dic"), "'", "\""), schema))

df.select("a", "b", "dic.*").show(truncate=False)

#+---+---+---+---+
#|a  |b  |c  |d  |
#+---+---+---+---+
#|1  |2  |1  |2  |
#|3  |4  |7  |0  |
#|5  |6  |5  |4  |
#+---+---+---+---+
```

If you don't know the all the keys, you can convert it to a map instead of struct then explode it and pivot to get keys as columns:

```
df = df.withColumn("dic", from_json(regexp_replace(col("dic"), "'", "\""), MapType(StringType(), StringType())))\
       .select("a", "b", explode("dic"))\
       .groupBy("a", "b")\
       .pivot("key")\
       .agg(first("value"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
#to convert pyspark df into pandas:
df=df.toPandas()

df["d"]=df["dic"].str.get("d")
df["e"]=df["dic"].str.get("e")
df=df.drop(columns=["dic"])
```

Returns:

```py
   a  b  d  e
0  1  2  1  2
1  3  4  7  0
2  5  6  5  4
```

Comment: I would like to do it as pandas UDF using spark not by converting the pyspark dataframe to pandas

Comment: What do you mean by ```pandas UDF```?

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski link : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf , its user defined function used in spark on groups. it is faster than converting to pandas dataframe as you can apply it on spark dataframe,however it is much slower than spark in built functionality